# Can't click moving div element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm not sure whats happening as I have divs on the page that are clickable.

The only difference with the one that isn't working is it is moving up the page.

You can see here that an element with the 'rising' class will move up the page. (1px every 50ms) until it reaches the top, then it will be removed...

```
setInterval(function () {
$('.rising').css('bottom', '+=1');

$(".rising").each(function () {
  if ($(this).offset().top <= -60) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
}, 50);
```

..before it reaches the top it should be clickable, here i've tried to add a class to it when clicked...

```
$('.rising').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass('blue');
});
```

but this doesn't work.

I've made sure it has a high z-index and is recognised when hovered over but no click.

http://www.gogeye.com/ - here is an example (click the grey play button after you've waited for all to load)

Comment: I run the `$('.rising').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass('blue');
});` on the web console and then click the `green` circle, it turns to `blue`. I think you have some issue in calling the function. And one more thing, your `.rising` class is dynamically added to dom, right ? in this case replace your `$('.rising').click(function () {});` to ` `$('.rising').on('click', function () {....});`. Try this, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind click using $('.rising').on('click.someNameSpace',function(){...}); in click event handler of **"play"** button from where you create rising elements. Once they all removed use 
$('.rising').off('click.someNameSpace'); --> this is because it will not consume more memory.

This will definitely solve your issue.